# insert key value pair to yaml file with correct indent by sed

Tags: bash, sed, yaml

A example of env.yaml file is shown below

```
package:
  name: "xyz"
  version: "2.3.1"

build:
  noarch: python

requirements:
  build:
    - python
```

how to add a `build/number:123` to the yaml file with correct indentation as follows?

```
package:
  name: "xyz"
  version: "2.3.1"

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 123

requirements:
  build:
    - python
```

The tricky thing is, there is a **build** key under **requirement** section, and I don't want any number added under that

Comment: Are you ok to use a syntax aware tool like `yq`? - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Answer (score 2):

sed is the best tool for doing simple s/old/new/ on individual strings, that is all. For anything more than that you should use awk (assuming you don't have access to a tool that understands whatever language your input file is written in, if applicable)

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^build:/ { f=1 }
!NF { prt(); f=0 }
{ print; prev=$0 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if (f) {
        sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",prev)
        print prev "number: 123"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
package:
  name: "xyz"
  version: "2.3.1"

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 123

requirements:
  build:
    - python
```

Answer (score 1):

If sed is to be used, and assuming the line sequence is fixed and that both the file content order is fixed and the values to insert:

```
sed -ri 's/^(\s+)noarch: python/&\n\1job: 123/' env.yaml
```

Comment: ...and assuming you have GNU sed (for `-r` and that particular syntax of `-i` and `\s`) and that `noarch: python` doesn't exist in any other part of the input and that `noarch: python` is always present in  the `build` section.

Comment: @EdMorton Esactly, this is what I worried, since there are projects don't have `norach: python` under build

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\s+\S/h;/^build:/{:a;n;/^$/!ba;x;s/\S.*/number: 123/p;x}' file
```

Make a copy of any indented line and then append the copy (replacing its content by the desired result) at the end of the `build:` stanza.

N.B. This is based on the data provided, the programmer can be more specific and choose an indented line like `name:` in the `package:` stanza if s/he prefers.

Comment: I tried it, seems not working, it only printed out the file in the terminal the `number:123` is not added

Comment: @SLN yes that is the correct behaviour, to update the file in place use the `-i` command line option or append ` > newfile` which will direct the results to `newfile`.